# RVAideMemoire::chisq.multcomp(x, p.method = "fdr")

Tags: r, chi-squared

I'm trying to perform pairwise chi-squared comparisons with RVAideMemoire::chisq.multcomp, but i'm getting implausible output.

Basically, i want to check if there are differences in diabetes prevalence across classes A, B and C. Here's an example.

````
data <- tibble(diabetes=sample(x=c(0,1), size=100, replace = TRUE), class=sample(x=c("A", "B", "C"), size=100, replace = TRUE))

chisq.test(table(data$diabetes, data$class))
chisq.multcomp(table(data$diabetes, data$class))
```

After running chisq.multcomp i get

>Pairwise comparisons using chi-squared tests   
>>data:  table(data$diabetes,data$class)     
>>>  12   14   14   17   17  
>>>14 0.80 -    -    -    -   
>>>14 0.80 1.00 -    -    -   
>>>17 0.76 0.80 0.80 -    -   
>>>17 0.76 0.80 0.80 1.00 -   
>>>26 0.29 0.29 0.29 0.51 0.51
>>>
>>>P value adjustment method: fdr

I'd expect the output to be a 3x3 matrix with pairwise p values.

Any explanations for that?
````